# Java Inheritance & OOP & AOP

Tags: java, annotations, language-features, aop

This is actually a semi-question, semi-discussion thread.
  I think a feature is needed in Java that a method(lets say "calcTotalX") can be defined via annotation in a class(i.e. ParallelExecuter) which will executed beforeStart/AfterEnd of another method (lets say doJob) in the same class. So that we can be sure that any class (lets say SortingParallelExecuter ) extending ParallelExecuter and overriding its "doJob" method don't have to know about X, risk forgetting processing X, handle operations events about X, etc.

My Question is that, is there anything in Java that I can do it like that, except AOP.
  I don't choose AOP because, it makes the code so much distributed and difficult to read.
  Also the concern here is class/method/attribute specific. So replication of behaviour is not needed for other class/method/attributes.

By the way, if you find this reasonable, please vote for the thread. Thnx

Ok, for being concrete I am adding a sample class which I use for dividing & paralelization.

```
public abstract class PartitionedParallelExecutor<T> {

private ExecutorService executorService;

private final List<PartitionErrorDesc<T>> errorMap     = new ArrayList<PartitionErrorDesc<T>>();
private final AtomicInteger totalExecutedJobCount      = new AtomicInteger();

private boolean shutdownForced = false;


private final int workerCount;
private final int partitionCount;
protected final List<T> sourceList; 

//Must be implemented via Extender class
protected abstract PartitionErrorDesc<T> doWork(List<T> subList);



public PartitionedParallelExecutor(int workerCount, int partitionCount, List<T> sourceList) {
    super();
    this.workerCount = workerCount;
    this.partitionCount = partitionCount;
    this.sourceList = sourceList;
}



public Object onPerPartitionFail(List<T> subList, PartitionErrorDesc<T> ped){return null;};

public Object onPerPartitionSuccess(List<T> subList){return null;};

public Object onAnyFailDoOnce() {return null;}

public Object onTotalSuccess() {return null;}


public final void  fireAndWait() {

    if(workerCount <= 0 || partitionCount <= 0 ||
            sourceList == null || sourceList.size() == 0){
        throw new IllegalArgumentException();
    }

    ExecutorService executorService = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(workerCount);
    this.executorService = executorService;

    List<List<T>> partitions = partitionList(sourceList, partitionCount);

    for (final List<T> subList : partitions) {

        executorService.execute(new Runnable() {
                                    @Override
                                    public void run() {

                                        PartitionErrorDesc<T> errorDesc = null;

                                        try {
                                            errorDesc = doWork(subList);
                                        } catch (Throwable e) {

                                            errorDesc = new PartitionErrorDesc<T>(subList);
                                            errorDesc.setSuccess(false);
                                            errorDesc.setE(e);
                                            errorDesc.setFailedAtItem(0);
                                        }   

                                        errorMap.add(errorDesc);

                                        if(errorDesc.isSuccess == false) { //failure

                                            onPerPartitionFail(subList, errorDesc);
                                            setShutdownForced(true);

                                            totalExecutedJobCount.addAndGet(errorDesc.getFailedAtItem());
                                            Thread.currentThread().interrupt();
                                            return;
                                        } else { //success
                                            totalExecutedJobCount.addAndGet(subList.size());
                                            onPerPartitionSuccess(subList);
                                        }
                                    }
        });
    }

    executorService.shutdown();

    try {
        executorService.awaitTermination(60, TimeUnit.MINUTES);
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {

        setShutdownForced(true);
        Thread.currentThread().interrupt();
    }

    if (!isShutdownForced()) {
        onTotalSuccess();
    } else {
        onAnyFailDoOnce();
    }
}


private List<List<T>> partitionList(List<T> sourceList , int partitionCount) {
    List<List<T>> partitions = new ArrayList<List<T>>();
    int totalSize = sourceList.size();

    int pageCount = partitionCount;
    int pageSize  = totalSize / pageCount; 
    int remainder = totalSize % (pageSize * pageCount);

    int fromIndex  = 0;
    int toIndex  = 0;
    for(int i = 0;  i < pageCount; i++) {

        fromIndex = toIndex;

        if(toIndex >= totalSize){
            break;
        }

        if ( remainder > i) {
            toIndex = toIndex + pageSize + 1;
        } else {
            toIndex = toIndex + pageSize;
        }

        List<T> subList = sourceList.subList(fromIndex,toIndex);

        partitions.add(subList);
    }

    return partitions;
}

public final void shutdownNow() {
    setShutdownForced(true);
    List<Runnable> runnables = executorService.shutdownNow();

    try {
        if(!executorService.awaitTermination(60,TimeUnit.SECONDS)) {
            LOG.error("pool didnt terminate after 60 seconds in shutdownNow");
        }
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        executorService.shutdownNow();
        Thread.currentThread().interrupt();
    }
}

public final boolean isShutdownForced() {
    return shutdownForced;
}

private synchronized void setShutdownForced(boolean shutdownForced) {
    this.shutdownForced = shutdownForced;
}
```

}

In this example, a programmer who wants to use the class above for doing his work in a multi-threaded way, he must implement "doJob()" but invoke "fireAndWait()". What a more neat way will be, implementing doJob & calling doJob. The rest of things like calculating "totalExecutedJobCount", onPerPartitionFail() must be implemented in AOP manner cross-cut to "doJob" method. Yes, we can implement this functionality in another class and yet any class extending PartitionedParallelExecutor can also extend this AOP behaviour as much as I know. At this point I ask, why these to things (calculating "totalExecutedJobCount", onPerPartitionFail()) must be in another class. They are related with that class, its attributes and method. Looking in an Object-Oriented manner, they must some methods in the same class and called whenever "doJob" ends. That is the question. Hope things are clear now. Thnx for your time.

Comment: Your prejudice against AOP does not make sense. I suggest you inform yourself and try it first before you say it is "difficult to read", because it is just not true. Distributed? No, on opposite: The aspect code is nicely modularised. It is easy to read, as it the core code because it is clean and free from cross-cutting concerns.

Comment: Thnx for your comment, but I am already using Spring AOP.

Comment: Spring AOP is "AOP light" with just method interception on Spring Beans. While the syntax is equivalent to AspectJ, the latter has many more possibilities and is more efficient because it does not need any dynamic proxies. It works on non-Spring Beans (i.e. normal POJOs), can intercept member variable read/write actions, constructor calls, static class initialisation, catch blocks and many more. But the best of all is the native syntax without the error-prone string-based annotation style.

Comment: Thanks for explaining, I am already aware of these. The critical point in my question is my AOP behaviour is about an attribute which is STRONGLY related to the class. (i.e. "calcTotalX" method is about X attribute of that class. It is an encapsulation issue. It is not about logging, security, etc. which is not related OO & which AOP really fits). This is my main point. If you explain that, then I will be convinced. Thnx

Comment: Your question is unclear, so I am unsure as to what I should explain except for my opinion that what you describe (before/after method interception, mixing in cross-cutting behaviour) is **exactly** what AOP has been invented for because OOP is not designed to do that.

Comment: Ok let me explain, AOP is for cross-cutting behaviour, but it is used for operations that are not related with class specific members. Like logging, security, etc. What if my cross-cutting behaviour is about something related to that class members, not things unrelated with class like logging & security, so that I want to package them with that class, library, make them inherit to extended classes? If question is not clear still, it is OK, thnx for your contribution.

Comment: With AspectJ it is absolutely possible and not even hard to interact with classes by replacing parameters in method calls, manipulating return values, changing members, calling methods, even introducing new members or methods etc. Packaging production aspects together with classes is something I do often. So again: What is your concrete problem? Please present some sample code and specific questions. StackOverflow is not for general debates and discussion, but for solving technical problems related to software development. I am glad to help if I can.

Comment: Updated the question, added a sample class & explained

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After our discussion in comments, reading your comment to Peter's answer and inspecting your lately added sample code, I actually understand your question but fail to understand why you see a problem there.

Your method `fireAndWait()` is actually a [Template Method](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Template_method_pattern), which is a well-proven OOP design pattern. I think it is totally fine to implement `doWork(List<T>)` as part of the algorithm, but instruct the user (via JavaDoc) not to call it himself but rely on its being called indirectly. For instance, you often implement `Runnable.run()` (even in your sample code!), but do not complain that it is not being called by yourself but indirectly via `Thread.start()` or `ExecutorService.execute()`. Isn't that the same pattern? Why should one "God method" do everything?

If you do not like your own pattern method approach, feel free to write a `PartitionedParallelExecutorStatisticsAspect` (sorry for the long name) taking care of this *aspect* (because that's what it is). Put it into the same package if you like, so it is near the abstract class, and let it do its job. God classes are equally bad as God methods, so arguably using AOP is also a viable alternative. Doing the (parallel partitioned) job is the core concern here, keeping stats is a secondary one. I would be fine with both approaches if implemented cleanly.

Although this topic is partly kinda philosophical and I have seen several close votes here, which is understandable, I am still hoping my comments are helpful. If so, feel free to accept the answer and close the topic so as not to make it an endless discussion thread.

Comment: Your explanation & Runnable.run() example is enough to accept for me. I only tried to seach if there could be better. But it seems that is not that big problem. One point I did not notice & understand was the pressure to close the issue. Nobody even told me about it. It seems a boring & non-practical, out of concept issue, but helps for learning & design. So why people bother? Thanx for contributing.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you should use code like this:

```
public final void doJob() {
    before();
    inside();
    after();
}

    protected void inside() {
}

private void before() {
}

private void after() {
}
```

Now you can't overload doJob(), but only inside() method, and you have interceptors: before() and after().

Comment: Yes, that seems actually a reasonable alternative solution until new feature. The only thing I object here is, programmer who extends this class have to be aware of overriding "inside" method but calling "doJob" instead of "inside", which makes it error prone. Thnx for your answer